# iOS : instead of "[app] is using your location" I'd like to display another text like "return to [app]", is this possible?

Tags: ios, geolocation, banner

Our app is using background location so this blue banner appears when leaving the app. Our users find it not clear to have a message saying the app is using the location, but would love to read "back to [app]" to be able to return to the app.

Is this possible? How could I customize the banner text? I saw apps doing it.

Comment: You can't change the message, but shouldn't typically see that bar if you have "always" permission and have enabled background location. How is your location usage configured?

Comment: Thank you Paul for the reply, I actually want to display the bar as it's a super convenient way to come back to the app, but I think the message "app is using your location" is a bit scary in terms of battery usage and I'd like instead to simply say "back to app" or "app is currently active", but I understand from your first part of the response that it's not possible. Is it possible with the red bars, in those bars the text is maybe customizable?

Comment: No, they are provided by iOS and you can't customise those